# $3D$ Plane centered in the origin into view of $2D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, graphing-functions

I have a plane that passes throught the origin. It has a red graph inside it, and a green vector (with origin in the center, $(0,0,0)$) that is orthogonal to the mentioned plane.

[image]

What I want is to obtain the view of the plane in an image 2D without losing the way the red plot is in the plane. How can I do this? I know that this is basically a rotation of the plane, but my calculations got very messy, so if someone could just give me clear instructions of how to do this as easy as possible, I will be thankful for it.

Comment: Are you doing this in some particular software system?

Comment: I'm using Python 3, but I wanted the general solution to write it because I could need to change of software (I'm still testing which language is better for my purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your function is $f(x,y,z)$ and you want to transform it into $g(x,y,0)$. You can do that by rotating the green vector $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ to point vertically up, along $z$ in your figure. First, calculate how much you need to rotate. The angle between the vertical and your normal to the plane, let's call it $\theta$ is given by the dot product:$$\cos\theta=\hat n\cdot\hat z=n_z$$
I assumed that $|\hat n|=1$. If $n_z=1$, you don't need to do anything. If $\hat n=-1$, the figure is upside down. So $$g(x,y,0)=f(-x,-y,0)$$
Normal up or down implies that your plane is the $xy$ plane.

If $|n_z|<1$, you can use the cross product to the the axis of rotation:
$$\hat r=\hat n\times\hat z=n_y\hat x-n_x\hat y$$
Then just use the [formula on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to calculate the rotation matrix $R$. Then calculate $$(x', y', z')^T=R(x,y,z)^T$$
If you did everything right, $z'=0$.
Then $g(x',y',0)=f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: You said that, and I quote, "I have a plane that passes throught the origin.". That's your first sentence.

Comment: I did overlook that, but I'm not the OP.

Comment: Yes, I said "I have a plane that passes throught the origin.". Let me read this a moment :) (thanks btw)

Comment: Sorry @saulspatz. I've accidentally attributed the statement to you.

Comment: No apology needed.